# Why isn't Attachment Delete action recognized when using it with URLFOR

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to use the following on a VF page, but I am getting an error when I try to save the VF page.

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Delete, attachment.Id)}"/>
```

> Error: Field $Action.Attachment.Delete does not exist. Check spelling

The following works in the same page:

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, attachment.Id)}" target="_blank">
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible via an output link. In years past you could use `/setup/own/deleteredirect.jsp?delID=<record id>` to do this but salesforce added a cross-site request forgery protection that prevents this from working without an additional confirmation.

Likewise the standard delete button actually includes a hidden `_CONFIRMATIONTOKEN` parameter that appears to be randomly generated for each page view.

So, if you want to do this you'll need to actually use an action component like apex:commandLink or apex:commandButton and call a controller method to perform the delete.

Comment: I think you are right. I will have to create and call a controller method, this action doesn't seem to be available for Attachments.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing quote on the first line. Try finishing it with `" target="_blank">`